# A question about ideals in operator algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Is it true that in a unital C*-algebra $A$ every closed left ideal $L\subset A$ is an intersection of all maximal left ideals which contain $L$? I know that $L$ is the left-kernel of some state but I am not sure whether this helps.

Edit: This is true. See Banach Algebras and the General Theory of *-Algebras: Volume 2, *-Algebras; Theorem 10.5.2(b).

Comment: Rather than delete the question you should add the answer as an answer! (And, after a couple of days, accept it)

Answer (score 1):

This is true. See Banach Algebras and the General Theory of *-Algebras: Volume 2, *-Algebras; Theorem 10.5.2(b).